# Install awscli on Windows

Tags: aws-cli

I'm using Windows, but trying to use cygwin on it (this probably doesn't have anything to do with it, but just to have some context). I have this problem installing awscli. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
$ pip install awscli
Collecting awscli
Using cached awscli-1.11.117-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.9 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.10 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): colorama<=0.3.7,>=0.2.5 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
Collecting PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10 (from awscli)
Using cached PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): botocore==1.5.80 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.5.80->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.5.80->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.5.80->awscli)
Installing collected packages: PyYAML, awscli
Running setup.py install for PyYAML
Complete output from command "c:\program files\python 3.5\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-build-97mqnqfq\PyYAML\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-rmh4ny9_-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\composer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
...

copying lib3\yaml\tokens.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
running build_ext
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
checking if libyaml is compilable
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python 3.5\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-build-97mqnqfq\PyYAML\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-rmh4ny9_-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-build-97mqnqfq\PyYAML
```

Answer (score 0):

The error output seems to be complaining about installing PyYAML

I would suggest you to follow this [guide](http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Awscli_in_cygwin) to install AWSCli on cygwin.